# Mapbox GL Js: what is the sourceID?

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-studio

The documentation for [Map.querySourceFeatures](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#map#querysourcefeatures) says it takes a parameter for `sourceID` - the ID of the vector tile or GeoJSON source. In their example, they add a source manually:

```
map.addSource('counties', {
    "type": "vector",
    "url": "mapbox://mapbox.82pkq93d"
});
```

And so the sourceID is `counties`.

If I create a Mapbox style in Mapbox Studio and publish it with a url, say:

```
mapbox://styles/mycoolcompany/mycoolmap123
```

and pass that directly to the `Map` constructor like this:

```
this.map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map',
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mycoolcompany/mycoolmap123',
    center: [-123.12, 49.28],
    zoom: 5,
});
```

How can I get (or set?) the styleID programatically? I'm trying different combinations of things from Mapbox Studio but `querySourceFeatures` returns an empty array every time with no exceptions or indication of what it's missing.

More succinctly: how do I use `querySourceFeatures` on a home-made Mapbox Studio Style?

(mapbox-gl 0.36.0)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't a public API to get all source IDs from a map, but

```
this.map.style.sourceCaches
```

will return an object wherein each key is a source ID and its value is a source cache (the class responsible for managing an individual source).

Note that Mapbox Studio automatically composites sources — so, if you've added a custom vector source, rather than having multiple vector sources you'll likely see just one (`composite`), and if you were to download the JSON stylesheet its URL would be something like

```
"url": "mapbox://mapbox.mapbox-streets-v7,mycoolcompany.randomsha"
```

so you'll *probably* be looking for a source called `composite`.

Comment: Thank you, that answers my question and I was able to get `querySourceFeatures` returning values. For anyone else puzzling over `querySourceFeatures` returning empty arrays, you will probably need to dive into `map.style.sourceCaches` described above and make a note of the `source` and `sourceLayer` names.

Comment: I think a more correct way would be `Object.keys(this.map.getStyle().sources)`. No need to go anywhere near `sourceCaches`.

Answer (score 2):

I understand it's an old post but putting the notes for someone it can help!

So, how do I get the `source` for querySourceFeatures()?

Here's the one-liner:

```
map.querySourceFeatures('composite', {sourceLayer: 'source-name', filter: [filters]})
```

So - what is `composite`, what is `sourceLayer`, what is `filter`?

Well first, we need to get to the `composite` source id and pass that to `source` param. Then we get the `tileset id` of the layer we are working on and pass that to `sourceLayer` param. And finally, get the applied filters on the layer we are working on and pass that to `filter` param.

To start with, we need to have the composite source id from the layer or the layer that you are working with:

```
// get the source from the layer, `mapLayerId` is the layer id
// this can be found in Mapbox Studio's styles editor
// or use your layer id if you created in the code 
var compositeSource = map.getLayer(mapLayerId.toString()).source;
```

Then to get the `tileset id`, we need to get what it's called the vectorlayer from that source, so:

```
console.log(map.getSource(compositeSource).vectorLayers);
```

The `vectorslayers` is essentially an JS object and contains all the tilesets that we have in Mapbox Studio.

Now, if we are dealing with only the `latest` vector layer, like me - because in my Mapbox Studio that's the tileset I created and all other tilesets are default ones and I am not using them, it will appear on the last element of the object. In this case, we can grab the last element of the returned object of `vectorslayers` and get its `id`, this id is the actual `tileset id`.

```
var compositeVectorLayerLength = map.getSource(compositeSource).vectorLayers.length - 1;
console.log(compositeVectorLayerLength);
// sourceId === tileset id which is known as vector layer id
var sourceId = map.getSource(compositeSource).vectorLayers[compositeVectorLayerLength].id;
```

We then get all the filters that were already applied on the layer we are working with:

```
var appliedFilters = map.getFilter(mapLayerId.toString());
console.log(appliedFilters);
```

Now, we call querySourceFeatures() passing all these values:

```
var resultFeatures = map.querySourceFeatures(compositeSource, {sourceLayer: sourceId, filter: appliedFilters});
```

The `resultFeatures` will be a JS object which will have all the features on the map.